# Pass parameter to an ajax call to read only specific field of a json file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a `example.json` file like this:

```
{
"User1": [{
           "Age":21,
           "Dogs":5,
           "Cats":0
          }],
"User2": [{
           "Age":19,
           "Dogs":2,
           "Cats":1
         }]
"User3": [ ...and so on...]
}
```

and a function `LoadData(UserName);` like this:

```
    LoadData(UserName) {
       $.ajax({
           url: "/users/example.json",
           dataType: "json",
           data: // How can i say to AJAX to parse only the UserName array? 
           success: function(response) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                $.("#ageID").text(response.Age);
                $.("#dogsID").text(response.Dogs);
                // And so on with the others fields
           }
       });
}
```

Also.. the function `LoadData(UserName);`  is called by the main html file (actually a .php script) with something like this:

```
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function() {

                LoadData("<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>");
          });

      </script>
</head>
```

Thanks!

**NOTE:** i perfectly know that all data i parse/use in this way will be perfectly visible to anyone. The example above is just, indeed, an example. The data i am dealing with is not private, rather is actually public.

Comment: You can't really tell $.ajax to do anything, you have to send something to the server and *then*  create a serverside script that sends only the parts you're asking for.

Comment: Is requirement to request only specific "userName" ? e.g., `LoadData(User1)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The server decides how it responds. You'll just have to deal with the returned data and ignore anything you don't need.

If you are also developing the server side application, then you can modify it to detect for example query parameters and react to those. Or use a different URL for getting only the `UserName` array.

I'm quessing here, but let's say you want to load all the user data only once but want to have a function that only deals with a single user at a time, try something like this:

```
function loadUsers() {
   return $.ajax({
       url: "/users/example.json",
       dataType: "json"
   });
}

function renderUser(user) {
    $("#ageID").text(user.Age);
    $("#dogsID").text(user.Dogs);
    // And so on with the others fields
}

function loadAndRender() {
    loadUsers().done(function(users) {
        renderUser(users.User1);
        renderUser(users.User2);
        // or loop over all of them, or have the required names as arguments in loadAndRender, etc
    });
}
```

Some additional notes and unsolicited advice:

- no need to call `parseJSON` in the `success` function (or the `done` callback in my example)
- in JS, only capitalize functions that are to be used as constructors. Don't capitalize anything else.
- `$.("#ageID")` should be `$("#ageID")` (or in my personal preference `$('#age')`)

Comment: i was imaging.. well, how can i pass "UserName" parameter to the success function? doing so i would be able to do something like "[...].text(response.UserName.Age);" ... but i cant figure it out how.. yeah im also developing server side, but sending "personal" requests to server-side script will result in XXXX calls to that script. While using a file with all informations will give me the possibility of run the server-side script only once, and then read from it with Ajax

Comment: if the `UserName` in your question is the one you want, then you can just use that in the success function, no need to "pass" it there. See [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for more.

Comment: You should also read about using `Deferred`s. The success function is actually deprecated, see here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Did you use the bracket notation, like this: `[...].text(response[UserName].Age)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try This

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="ageID"></p>
<p id="dogsID"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadData(UserName) {
   $.ajax({
       url: "ajax.php",
       dataType: "json",
       data: {UserName:UserName},
       success: function(response) {
            $("#ageID").text(response[0].Age);
            $("#dogsID").text(response[0].Dogs);
       }
   });
}
LoadData('User2');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

## ajax.php page

```
<?php
$jsonfile = file_get_contents("example.json");
$obj = json_decode($jsonfile);
echo json_encode($obj->$_REQUEST['UserName']);
?>
```

## example.json

```
{
"User1": [{
           "Age":21,
           "Dogs":5,
           "Cats":0
          }],
"User2": [{
           "Age":19,
           "Dogs":2,
           "Cats":1
         }]
}
```